# Groupby pandas dataframe to produce a single list column of distinct groups and counts

Tags: python, pandas

still trying to think through how to describe this properly (will update the question), but here's my `have`/`want` minimal, reproducible, example of what I'm trying to do.

```
have = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,2,2], 'grp': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 'val': [5,4,3,2,1]})
>>> have
   id grp  val
0   1   a    5
1   1   b    4
2   1   c    3
3   2   d    2
4   2   e    1

want = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'results': [[('a', 5), ('b', '4'), ('c', 3)], [('d',2), ('e',1)]]})

>>> want
   id                   results
0   1  [(a, 5), (b, 4), (c, 3)]
1   2          [(d, 2), (e, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try groupby `id` column then zip the `grp` and `val` columns

```py
out = (have.groupby('id')
       .apply(lambda g: list(zip(g['grp'], g['val'])))
       .rename('result')
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

   id                    result
0   1  [(a, 5), (b, 4), (c, 3)]
1   2          [(d, 2), (e, 1)]
```

If you want to zip more than two columns into list of tuple, you can also use `df.itertuples`, but `df.to_records` referenced in other's answer is also fine.

```py
out = (have.groupby('id')
       .apply(lambda g: list(g[['grp', 'val']].itertuples(index=False)))
       .rename('result')
       .reset_index())
```

```
print(out)

   id                    result
0   1  [(a, 5), (b, 4), (c, 3)]
1   2          [(d, 2), (e, 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
want = (have
 .assign(result=have[['grp','val']].agg(tuple, 1))
 .groupby('id')['result']
 .agg(list).reset_index()
 )
```

Comment: Editing from a phone :p

Comment: `.assign(result=have[['grp','val']].agg(tuple, 1))` is giving an error *ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1*. I guess, you'd have chain `.to_numpy` + `tolist`.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get your data as list tuples is to use [`df.to_records`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_records.html). Then `groupby.agg`.

```
have.assign(
    res=have[["grp", "val"]].to_records(index=False).tolist()
).groupby("id", as_index=False)["res"].agg(list)


#    id                       res
# 0   1  [(a, 5), (b, 4), (c, 3)]
# 1   2          [(d, 2), (e, 1)]
```

Comment: Nice one, you could use `assign` to have a pipeline and avoid modifying the input ;)

Comment: Ahh yes. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit the answer. @mozway

Comment: How is this answer different to mine except it's long?

Comment: I don't use df.apply, it's damn slow.... It's ok, typing from phone so don't have benefit of big screen.

Comment: @wwnde Yeah, `df.apply` over axis 1 can be slow. What I wanted to say is `df.to_records` is a function whose only purpose is to give a list of tuples but `df.apply` applies a function on the columns. I put an alternative answer suggesting to use a much more specialized function `df.to_records`.